# Postgres get function owner

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, functions, role, access-control

I would like to be able to get a table of function names and function owner names.

Currently, this query returns a list of functions for a given schema:

```sql
  SELECT  proname
  FROM    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
  JOIN    pg_catalog.pg_proc p
  ON      pronamespace = n.oid
  WHERE   nspname = '<%= schema_name %>';
```

I can see there is a `proowner` column which returns the ID of the role.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/catalog-pg-proc.html

What I would like is something that returns the name of the owner, I just don't know enough SQL yet to figure out how to JOIN the tables etc..

```
|function_name|function_owner|
______________________________
|func1        |func1_owner   |
|func2        |func2_owner   |
```

If someone could explain how to do this I would be very grateful!

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a simple and a complicated way.

The complicated way is to join with `pg_roles` and get the user name from there.

But since PostgreSQL hackers don't want to type more than necessary, they came up with something else:

Internally, every object is not identified by its name (which is mutable) but by its “object ID”. This is the number that is for example used in the `proowner` column of `pg_proc`.

Now there are the so-called “[object identifier types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html)”. Internally such a type is just the `oid`, but the type output function, which is used for display of the type, renders it as the object's name.

Put that together with PostgreSQL's type cast operator `::`, and you can do:

```
SELECT proname,
       proowner::regrole
FROM pg_proc
WHERE pronamespace::regnamespace::text = 'public';
```

Additional hint: maybe you would prefer `oid::regprocedure` over `proname`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I learned something new about Postgres too as I thought I would :)